# How to force LDAPS for SQL*Plus name lookups

Tags: oracle, ssl, ldap, sqlplus

So, when configuring SQL*Plus for LDAP name lookups as per Oracle docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/ldap.htm#NETRF011

They list an optional secure port:

```
host:port[:sslport]
```

No matter how this is configured I never see any connections to the secure LDAP port. On top of that I don't see any way to configure the SQL*Plus client to do a secure lookup either. So, aside from missing any configurations, why is the secure port option even there?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am answering you completely but I have a feeling you want to look at the sqlnet.ora file. This file resides in ORACLE_HOME/network/admin folder (on client as well as server)

Comment: I've already checked the docs for sqlnet.ora, and most of their SSL stuff refer to 2way client cert checking, but we're not doing this, just anonymous LDAP lookups with the SSL port. I've tried using the "SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION" option set to true, but no behavior changes.